# How to convert text in different character set

Tags: character-encoding, converters

I have some text files in character set of GB2312, it is text file but shows text like:
=B2=E2=CA=D4=D6=D0=CE=C4
I wonder if there is a way to type in these text and translate them into the readable format?

Thanks.

Comment: What language, framework, platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content appears to be Quoted Printable (QP) encoded, so you need first a QP decoder. Google for "quote printable" and the name of your favorite programming language. Using an [online decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp) and opening the result in a program that can interpret GB2312, one can see that the data starts with 测试中.